# How to run TASKKILL in HTA?

Tags: cmd.exe, process

all help/suggestions its appreciated.

I want make a **HTA** able to run **taskkill** commands. I have a working one, but in cmd way. Just want migrate it to HTA, because look proper.

Here my CMD:

```
@echo off
title "app title"
color 1f
echo   --------------------------------------   
echo   Version 1   
echo   --------------------------------------
echo.
echo  Press Enter to run...
echo.
pause>nul
taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq APPNAMEHERE*"
cls
color 2f
echo.
echo.
echo  SUCCESS: Press [Enter] to close.
pause>nul
```

I made this not no working:

```
<html><head>
<HTA:APPLICATION border="thin" borderStyle="normal" caption="yes" maximizeButton="no" minimizeButton="no" showInTaskbar="no" innerBorder="no" navigable="yes" scroll="no" scrollFlat="no"/>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Sub btnRun_Click
wshshell.Run("cmd.exe taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq APPNAMEHERE*"")
End Sub
</script>

<body>
<p>Press [ Run ] to start.
<p><input type="button" id="btnRun" name="btnRun" value="Run" onclick="btnRun_Click">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to scape the double quotes `"` with double quotes

```
wshshell.Run("cmd.exe taskkill /fi ""WindowTitle eq APPNAMEHERE*""") ' Here
```

Cheers

Comment: sorry still no working